# jQuery - Output only even numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I'm finding the height of a div (which is computed by a percentage), halving that number and then using it to affect another div. You don't need to know the nitty details but the halving is causing a problems as you can't half a pixel (to my knowledge!)

Simply.. my question is can I limit my output to only even numbers? If the height of my div is 345 can the output be 346..? Some kind of 'if' it's an odd number add 1, or perhaps there's already something that does this?

My code is as simple as:

```
var height = $(this).height();
```

Many thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You can check for a remainder using [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) (`%`). If there is a remainder after checking height modulo 2, you'll know the number is odd:

```
if (height % 2 === 1)
    height++;
```

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining the reasoning behind this solution instead of just dumping code.

Comment: Hi, I'm coming to you first because it's the simplest.. but I've only been learning jQuery for 2 weeks and not sure how this should fit into my code! This is my var:

var new_watch_height = ((window_height / 100) * 55) -40;

Comment: @JakeHills you can add it straight after your `var height = $(this).height();` declaration on the line below. :) **Edit:** if your new variable is `new_watch_height`, simply replace `height` in my code example with that. `if (new_watch_height % 2 === 1) new_watch_height++;`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was doing but it's still console logging odd numbers... `var new_watch_height = ((window_height / 100) * 55) -40;` `if (new_watch_height % 2 === 1) new_watch_height++;` `console.log(new_watch_height);`

Comment: Also, while you're here.. Am I able to round them up? So I only ever get full, even numbers?

Comment: Ah, you need to wrap your `((window_height / 100) * 55) -40` with `Math.round()`: `Math.round((window_height / 100) * 55) -40)`. :) [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/63HGV/).

Comment: Yes, thank you. Took a bit of jigging to fit into my code, but got it working.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var height = $(item).height() % 2 == 1 ? $(item).height()+ 1 : $(item.height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution (since I dont know if there is something better):

```
var height = $(item).height;
if(height%2 != 0) { height += 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.floor` after halving to »round« towards the lower integer.